# Where does this Martin Luther quote come from?

Tags: martin-luther

"Sin is essentially a departure from God." -Martin Luther

Which work does this quote come from?

Comment: Earliest published versions in Internet Archive: [1875](https://archive.org/details/lostforever00towngoog/page/n257?q=%22Sin+is+essentially+a+departure+from+God%22) and [1877](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.94281/page/n631?q=%22Sin+is+essentially+a+departure+from+God%22) (Both attributed to Luther without citation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to *God is for Us: 52 Readings from Romans,* by Simon Ponsonby: "During the Diet of Augsburg Luthor wrote to Melancthon, 'Sin is essentially a departure from God.'" Quote is credited in that book to *Watchwords for the Warfare of Life,* Vol. 1, T. Nelson and Sons.

eBook URL: [God is for Us](https://books.google.com/books?id=M3VFBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=67&f=false)

Comment: Of course, the quoted source was probably itself a book of quotes, so it's not Luther's original source, but his letter would be.

Comment: I'm not finding it in the [versions of Watchwords available on Internet Archive](https://archive.org/search.php?query=Watchwords+for+the+Warfare+of+Life)

Answer (score 2):

Luther's commentary on Genesis 3:9:

> That is the very nature of sin, the farther a man departs from God the farther he wants to depart. And thus the man who has once departed and apostasized from God goes on departing and departing to all eternity.